# Monitoring bandwidth on a Server 2008 box

Tags: bandwidth, watchguard

I have a Server 2008 Web edition box sitting behind a Watchguard Firebox X Edge. It is a standalone web server, no other machines on the LAN with it. Is there some software out there that will let me monitor bandwidth only? I don't need any other features, just the total amount of IN/OUT bandwidth in an easy to read format. No additional servers, VMs or anything of the sort can be used, it needs to be software that will run on a Windows platform. I would use something like MRTG, but my firewall does not appear to support SNMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Netmeter](http://www.metal-machine.de/readerror/) is a light-weight bandwidth monitor that will give you real-time In/Out bandwidth stats in a graph.  The utility sits in the system tray when you're not using it.  I use this on all of my servers and it's ideal to see how much traffic a machine is generating at a glance.

As well as real-time stats, it also provides you with daily, weekly and monthly bandwidth usage.

Answer (score 1):

Why not setup a perfmon counter to log the network traffic to a file or a database?

Comment: This was my first thought, but I was purposely looking for something easy to view for the developers to glance at on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use MRTG or similar with window SNMP service? To install SNMP in windows 2008 navigate to "Add Feature" in the server setup dialogue. Once installed you should be able to use the Services list to configure and start SNMP.

See:
[How to Install](http://grinding-it-out.blogspot.com/2009/01/setting-up-snmp-on-windows-server-2008.html)

[General Info](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverManagement/thread/a10ae19b-c4d7-4372-bda0-c771c6d4cca3)

[Technet article on SNMP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726987.aspx)